# Python for loop over two lists for all the pairs

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, iteration

I have a dataframe with date, id - I need to pull out each date and id combination and create a new dataframe.

```
  date           id
2016-05-13       abc
2016-05-13       pqr
2016-05-14       abc
2016-05-14       pqr

ids = list(sorted(set(df['id'])))
Out: ['abc','pqr']

dates = list(sorted(set(df[df.id == ids[i]]['date'])))
Out: ['2016-05-13','2016-05-14']

for i in range(0,len(ids)):
    df2 = df[(df.date == dates[i]) & (df.id == id[i])]
```

The above code is resulting the output (`df2`) for relative index values only (First date, First Id & Second date, Second Id), but I need the output for all the pairs. Please let me know what to change in the loop?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

to get all the pairs `ids` vs. `dates`, you could use `itertools` as

```
import itertools

for iid, ddate in itertools.product(ids, dates):
    df2 = df[(df.date == ddate) & (df.id == iid)]
```

Comment: itertools is a fine answer, but this snippet doesn't even work.  You just reassign some slice of `df` to the same variable `df2` over and over again.

Comment: @piRSquared from what I understood, the OP wanted to generate such slice for each pair of id/date - slice which is presumably subject to further processing...

Answer (score 0):

Create a new dataframe with each `id` in columns and each `date` in rows.  You can fill it in later.

```
pd.DataFrame([], set(df.date), set(df.id))
```

[image]

---

if you just want the list of combinations

```
pd.MultiIndex.from_product([set(df.id), set(df.date)]).tolist()

[('pqr', '2016-05-14'),
 ('pqr', '2016-05-13'),
 ('abc', '2016-05-14'),
 ('abc', '2016-05-13')]
```